# Retromod: where to find rigid 26in fork for disc brake?

Tags: disc-brake, fork

looking to replace my 90s Marin rigid fork (canti) for on with a caliper mount for disc brake.

[The closest I found was this but it is hi-ten.](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/392277420841?var=0&mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=710-53481-19255-0&campid=5338268676&toolid=10044&customid=CjwKCAjwtuOlBhBREiwA7agf1k-AnLyDpDYNy5z9rcgXtqUPOs22fDBJBGmF_dDoUF_3WXikBme8cRoCBG8QAvD_BwE) Also I am not sure why they drilled a hole at the junction between the dropout and the fork, that concerns me a bit.

Other than that they would be surly type and I don't need the ugly screw on the site (also, it's expensive ...)

threaded or not does not matter, I can change the headset.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using disk brakes, you don't necessarily need to limit yourself to forks that are specifically for 26" wheels. What you should pay attention to is the rake/offset and the axle to crown-race distance, both of which will ideally be very close to your current fork.

Specific product recommendations are out of scope for this site. That said…[this Crust fork](https://crustbikes.com/collections/forks/products/disc-romanceur-fork) has a relatively short axle/crown measurement that might make it an OK fit.